# Escape two backslashes and apostrophe in an active record query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a question in the database stored as the string

```
"What are the symptoms of crohn\\'s disease?"
```

How do I find all questions which contain "\\'"

I tried Question.where('question like "\\\\\'") doesn't work.

Comment: Use ctl-k or the `{}` editor button to highlight code blocks inline. I started to edit but it isn't clear how many `\` are in your code and how many you needed to make it display on screen here.

Comment: the number is as shown in the highlighted code.

Comment: I mean in the `Question.where()` example.  Displayed above are 5 \ but in the original code when editing, there are 9 \. Please highlight that inline with the correct number of \

Comment: I tried 5 backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

It worked took 13backslashes and an apostrophe